# python virtual environment

Tags: linux, shell, python, virtualenv

I have to install `python` package locally/globally on a machine using `pip`, so for I do not want to install `pip` on local machine. I can successfully create a new virtual environment using

```
easy_install virtualenv-15.0.1.tar.gz    # (this package is present on machine)
mkdir /tmp/tmp_env
virtualenv /tmp/tmp_env/ENV
/tmp/tmp_env/ENV/bin/pip install PACKAGENAME
```

But when I do so it installs this package on virtual environment. I wish to install package on local environment so that even if I remove/deactivate virtualenv package should be present on local env.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have the `pip` in the virtualenv write to another location by user `--user` or `--install-option`:

```
 PYTHONUSERBASE=/path/to/your/dist-or-site-packages /tmp/tmp_env/ENV/bin/pip install --user
```

or

```
/tmp/tmp_env/ENV/bin/pip --install-option="--prefix=/path/to/python/install"
```

You should however not doing this kind of cludging at all. If you don't want to install `pip`, just install the PACKAGENAME with `easy_install` directly, or download the source packages tar.gz file, extract it and run

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're in a new Virtual env, anything you install will only be specific to that env. Move out to a global shell where you haven't sourced the new ENV or don't use `/tmp/tmp_env/ENV/bin/pip install PACKAGENAME`. Instead use the pip you have in the shell's global `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not have pip on my localenv neither I want to download it on localenv.

So can't we download any package from "pip in virtaulenv" to "localenv"